# Completable Future with Timeout not working

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice, completable-future

I am new Completable Future. I am trying to call a method parallel for a list of elements (which are arguments) and then combine the results to create a final response. I am also trying to set up timeout of 50 ms so that if the call doesn't return in 50 ms I will return a default value.

So far I ve tried this :

```
    {

     List<ItemGroup> result = Collections.synchronizedList(Lists.newArrayList());

    try {
     List<CompletableFuture> completableFutures = response.getItemGroupList().stream()
     .map(inPutItemGroup -> 
       CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
           final ItemGroup itemGroup = getUpdatedItemGroup(inPutItemGroup);               //call which I am tryin to make parallel

           // this is thread safe
           if (null != itemGroup) {
                  result.add(itemGroup); //output of the call
           }
        }, executorService).acceptEither(timeoutAfter(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),inPutItemGroup))  //this line throws error     
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

// this will wait till all threads are completed
    CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()]))
                        .join();
} catch (final Throwable t) {
     final String errorMsg = String.format("Exception occurred while rexecuting parallel call");
                log.error(errorMsg, e);
                result = response.getItemGroupList(); //default value - return the input value if error
    }

    Response finalResponse = Response.builder()
                    .itemGroupList(result)
                    .build();

    }

     private <T> CompletableFuture<T> timeoutAfter(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) {
            CompletableFuture<T> result = new CompletableFuture<T>();

            //Threadpool with 1 thread for scheduling a future that completes after a timeout
            ScheduledExecutorService delayer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            String message = String.format("Process timed out after %s %s", timeout, unit.name().toLowerCase());
            delayer.schedule(() -> result.completeExceptionally(new TimeoutException(message)), timeout, unit);
            return result;
     }
```

But I keep getting error saying :

```
 error: incompatible types: ItemGroup cannot be converted to Consumer<? super Void>
    [javac]                             itemGroup))

incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    [javac]                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]     equality constraints: CompletableFuture
    [javac]     lower bounds: Object
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
```

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong here ? And please correct me if I am going in the wrong direction.

Thanks.

Comment: @Lino Sorry there was a typo. Updated the code.

Comment: Side note: you should correct your intendation otherwise it's hard to distinguish between calls on the CompletableFuture and calls on the stream (`acceptEither(...)` and `collect(...)` look like they're on the same level but they aren't).

Comment: According to the Javadoc that second parameter to acceptEither would be "the action to perform before completing the returned CompletionStage" - assuming you probably don't want to perform any action on the result so just pass the identity consumer and provide the default value via the timed out future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
acceptEither(timeoutAfter(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), inPutItemGroup))
```

you’d need

```
applyToEither(timeoutAfter(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), x -> inPutItemGroup)
```

to compile the code. “accept” is an action consuming a value without returning a new value, “apply” is an action that produces a new value.

However, there’s still a logical error. The future returned by `timeoutAfter` will be completed *exceptionally*, so dependent stages will get completed exceptionally as well, without evaluating functions, so this chaining method is not suitable for replacing an exception with a default value.

Even worse, fixing this would create a new future which gets completed by either source future, but that does not affect the `result.add(itemGroup)` action performed in one of the source futures. In your code, the resulting future is only used to wait for the completion, but not for evaluating the result. So when your timeout elapses, you would stop waiting for the completion, whereas there still might be background threads modifying the list.

The correct logic is to separate the steps of fetching the value, which can get superseded by a default value on timeout, and the step of adding the result, either the fetched value or default value, to the result list. Then, you can wait for the completion of all `add` actions. On a timeout, there might be still ongoing `getUpdatedItemGroup` evaluations (there is no way to stop their execution), but their result would be ignored, so it doesn’t affect the result list.

It’s also worth pointing out that creating a new `ScheduledExecutorService` for every list element (that is not shut down after use, to make matters worse), is not the right approach.

```
// result must be effectively final
List<ItemGroup> result = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
List<ItemGroup> endResult = result;
ScheduledExecutorService delayer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
try {
    CompletableFuture<?>[] completableFutures = response.getItemGroupList().stream()
    .map(inPutItemGroup ->
        timeoutAfter(delayer, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> getUpdatedItemGroup(inPutItemGroup), executorService),
            inPutItemGroup)
         .thenAccept(itemGroup -> {
            // this is thread safe, but questionable,
            // e.g. the result list order is not maintained
            if(null != itemGroup) result.add(itemGroup);
         })
    )
    .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new);

    // this will wait till all threads are completed
    CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures).join();
} catch(final Throwable t) {
    String errorMsg = String.format("Exception occurred while executing parallel call");
    log.error(errorMsg, e);
    endResult = response.getItemGroupList();
}
finally {
    delayer.shutdown();
}

Response finalResponse = Response.builder()
    .itemGroupList(endResult)
    .build();
```

```
private <T> CompletableFuture<T> timeoutAfter(ScheduledExecutorService es,
    long timeout, TimeUnit unit, CompletableFuture<T> f, T value) {

    es.schedule(() -> f.complete(value), timeout, unit);
    return f;
}
```

Here, the `supplyAsync` produces a `CompletableFuture` which will provide the result of the `getUpdatedItemGroup` evaluation. The `timeoutAfter` invocation will schedule a completion with a default value after the timeout, without creating a new future, then, the dependent action chained via `thenAccept` will add the result value to the `result` list.

Note that a `synchronizedList` allows adding elements from multiple threads, but adding from multiple threads will result in an unpredictable order, unrelated to the order of the source list.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `acceptEither` looks like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> acceptEither(
    CompletionStage<? extends T> other, 
    Consumer<? super T> action
) {
```

And the line which is throwing the error looks like this:

```
.acceptEither(
     timeoutAfter(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
     inPutItemGroup
)
```

So you see that you try to pass an `ItemGroup` as a `Consumer<? super T>` where `T` was infered to be `Void` and hence you get the expected error:

```
error: incompatible types: ItemGroup cannot be converted to Consumer<? super Void>
```

Comment: so I cannot use acceptEither  ? I am confused. How do I return the default value if the timeout exceeds ?

Comment: @user3407267 you could use `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`, catch the `TimeoutException` and then return your default value

Comment: does the get(timeout) is for single call in the parallel calls from list or is it for all the calls in the list ?

Comment: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    [javac]                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]     equality constraints: CompletableFuture

Comment: With get I still see exception for collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Can I do like this -  CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()]))
                    .get(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); ?

Comment: @user3407267 I honestly don't know if your current setup will work for your requirements, do you really need the calls to be async. What brought you to this decision?

Comment: My application timeout is 50 ms. The single call getUpdatedItemGroup self takes 45 ms - this is a dependency call which I don't ve control. So I am trying to make a parallel call for all the items so that all will be done in 45 sec.

Comment: @user3407267 How much items are you expecting? And wish to execute concurrently?

Comment: around 10 times and yes.

Comment: @user3407267 so you can't let your application wait for half a second? This is in no way a sufficient amount of items to use multi threading (it probably will take longer than half a second for the scheduler to schedule and execute those tasks), just execute them sequentially